# How do you tab between elements in react-modal using user-event?

Tags: testing, focus, react-testing-library, react-modal, user-event

When writing a test using [@testing-library/react](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library) and [@testing-library/user-event](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/), I am unable to get `userEvent.tab()` to work inside of the React Modal component. I think it may have something to do with passing the correct `focusTrap` argument to the `tab` function, but I have been unable to get it to work.

Here's a link to a CodeSandbox with a minimum reproduction of the issue: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-mestorf-qx6j8?file=/src/__tests__/index.js)

How can I use user-event to tab between elements inside of a react-modal?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been a bug with user-event, which will be fixed in version 14. Here is a link to an issue with a discussion about this topic https://github.com/testing-library/user-event/issues/820